# Save all values in Uppercase Laravel 5+

Tags: laravel-5

What would be the best way to save all values in the database as uppercase. So before saving convert all strings to uppercase. I see options to use Events or a trait would probably be best but not quite sure how to achieve this. I do not want to create accessors & mutators for each of my fields.

Got this from : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/listen-to-any-saveupdatecreate-event-for-any-model

```
trait Trackable {
public static function bootTrackable()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        // blah blah
    });

    static::updating(function ($model) {
        // bleh bleh
    });

    static::deleting(function ($model) {
        // bluh bluh
    });
}
}
```

Im not sure how I would be able to get the actual request values to convert them to uppercase?

Comment: _I do not want to create accessors & mutators for each of my fields._ Why? This is _exactly_ what accessors and mutators are for? Although I’m not sure why you want to store things all-uppercase and not natural case, as it’s going to hard to re-format all-uppercase strings to their original case.

Comment: Client's needs, no matter how you try to convince them! We have about 20 Models and some of them have a lot of columns to go create all of them will be a pain. So I want a simple global method to go this and when we have convinced them not to save everything to uppercase easy to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was a lot easier than I through. Solution that is working for me using traits, posting it if anyone also run into something like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait SaveToUpper
{
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);

        if (is_string($value))
            $this->attributes[$key] = trim(strtoupper($value));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
For Getting values as upper case you can add this to the trait or just add it as a function in the model:

```
public function __get($key)
{
    if (is_string($this->getAttribute($key))) {
        return strtoupper( $this->getAttribute($key) );
    } else {
        return $this->getAttribute($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is an amazing answer!

Comment: Is it possible somehow to make the same for getter

Comment: @lewis4u I updated the answer to add a function to convert all values to uppercase this will return everything as uppercase.

Comment: Cool. I voted you up already. If I could I would do it again :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not good... I have a pivot table "article_tag" and if i call $article->tags I get null...can we try to fix this together? Setter is fine, but the getter needs to be changed.

Answer (score 8):

As @Louwki said, you can use a Trait to do that, in my case I did something like this:

```
trait SaveToUpper
{
    /**
     * Default params that will be saved on lowercase
     * @var array No Uppercase keys
     */
    protected $no_uppercase = [
        'password',
        'username',
        'email',
        'remember_token',
        'slug',
    ];

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
        if (is_string($value)) {
            if($this->no_upper !== null){
                if (!in_array($key, $this->no_uppercase)) {
                    if(!in_array($key, $this->no_upper)){
                        $this->attributes[$key] = trim(strtoupper($value));
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (!in_array($key, $this->no_uppercase)) {
                    $this->attributes[$key] = trim(strtoupper($value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your model, you can specify other keys using the 'no_upper' variable. Like this:

```
// YouModel.php
protected $no_upper = ['your','keys','here'];
```

Comment: Brilliant, I like the option to exclude certain fields!

Comment: @ZtuX can you help to create a universal getter like that? I have made one but now when I call related models for example $article->tags it returns null...